# Powershell - extract specific items from zip then send a message (loop with message box)

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, command, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to achieve the following with this powershell script.

1. Copy any .zip file from folder dropfilehere to folder IN.
2. For each .zip file in folder "IN" open the zip file, find only the .csv file.
3. When .csv file is found, extract it to $dst under name DB.csv (overwrite old file).
4. Empty contents of folders "dropfilehere" and "IN"
5. Finally, when all the above is done, create a popup box with a message to the user using wscriptshell -
   This is the issue. When the message is sent, the user gets 10+ popup boxes or an endless loop of them.

In the background i see cmd.exe and conhost.exe processes appearing as each popup box gets created.

I use a batch file to call the powershell script.

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\pathtoscript\call.ps1
exit
```

The script is:

```
  $dst = "C:\Testing\DB"
Copy-item -Path "C:\Users\user\dropfilehere\*.zip" -destination "C:\Testing\Other\In" -Force
Foreach ($zipfile in (Get-ChildItem "C:\Testing\Other\In\*.zip" -Recurse)) {
Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
$zipFile = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipfile)
$zipFile.Entries | where {$_.Name -like '*.csv'} | foreach {$FileName = $_.Name
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($_, "$dst\DB.csv", $true)}
$zipFile.Dispose()
Remove-Item "C:\Testing\Other\In\*" -Recurse -Force
Remove-Item "C:\Users\user\dropfilehere\*" -Recurse -Force
$org="Name of Org"
$timeout = 60 # in seconds
$ws = New-Object -ComObject "Wscript.Shell"
$intButton = $ws.Popup("A new update message here`n
Another message here.",$timeout,$org, 0)
}
exit
```

Comment: First things first, you should rarely ever use `exit` at the end of a batch file, use either `Exit /B` or `GoTo :EOF`, if you really need it. In this case you should simply remove that line, because the script will end as soon as it has no more commands to run anyhow.

Comment: You're calling `$ws.Popup(...)` _for each file_ returned from `Get-ChildItem "C:\Testing\Other\In\*.zip" -Recurse`. This would be more obvious if you formatted your code with indentation.

Comment: @mklement0 How would I go about updating that and make the code as short as possible  ? I added this piece as the zip file can be quite large 100-500mb and rather than waiting for it to extract everything, i have it extract just one file.
I know it's a bit rough and cluttered, but thanks for your help.

Comment: @mklement0
When the file has been extracted from the zip file, i want the original zip file to be deleted, and for the user to receive a message popup box that says the file has been extracted.
Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: @mklement0 I just updated the description and included step by step what I'm trying to achieve with the script and where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is code *inside* your `foreach` loop that should be placed *after* it, as shown below (properly indenting your code would have made that more obvious):

```bash
Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

$dst = "C:\Testing\DB"
Copy-item -Path "C:\Users\user\dropfilehere\*.zip" -destination "C:\Testing\Other\In" -Force

# Process all files.
foreach ($zipfile in (Get-ChildItem "C:\Testing\Other\In\*.zip" -Recurse)) {
  $zipFile = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipfile)
  $zipFile.Entries | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*.csv' } |
    ForEach-Object { 
      [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($_, "$dst\DB.csv", $true) 
    }
  $zipFile.Dispose()
}

# Remove the folders containing the original *.zip files.
Remove-Item "C:\Testing\Other\In\*" -Recurse -Force
Remove-Item "C:\Users\user\dropfilehere\*" -Recurse -Force

# Show a message box.
$org = "Name of Org"
$timeout = 60 # in seconds
$ws = New-Object -ComObject "Wscript.Shell"
$intButton = $ws.Popup("A new update message here`nAnother message here.", $timeout, $org, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's still doing the same thing. It's creating a dozen of popup boxes with the message and in the background i see as many cmd.exe and conhost.exe processes being created as the message boxes appear.

Comment: Also, it's taking an average 30-60 seconds longer for the file to extract using this script, any particular reason ?

If i use the script i provided via TS it only gives one message box. If I call it via cmd then it creates more boxes with both scripts (the old one and the updated one).

Comment: @CaTieKiop1, assuming you invoke the above code only once, it only ever creates _one_ message box. If you see more, the problem must lie elsewhere - instantiating `WScript.Shell` happens _in-process_, so it doesn't explain new `cmd.exe `and `conhost.exe` processes.

Comment: @CaTieKiop1, as for the command taking longer: your original code is broken, in that it removes the directory whose files are being enumerated in every iteration. This means that (a) the code never worked correctly to begin with and (b) likely only processed _some_ of the ZIP files, so, yes, it's possible that the fixed code now runs longer.

Comment: Fixed it. It was all due to timing between scans. The TS was set on 5 and it worked with old code. The other software that called this script (including old code and new) was using 1 second scan, so both scripts would throw the error even though they properly processed the files.

Thank you for your help and optimizing the code !

Comment: Glad to hear it's resolved, @CaTieKiop1; my pleasure.